# If my PC is connected with wi-fi then I can't connect my Bluetooth headphones with the PC

Tags: wireless, bluetooth

I am Using Asus x556u, Ubuntu 16.04.02, and Remax RB 195-HB Bluetooth headphones. If I'm connected to wi-fi then I can't connect my Bluetooth headphones. If I disconnect wi-fi then I can add headphones, but after I connect with wi-fi the headphones disconnect automatically.

I have used blueman also but that doesn't fix it. Is there any solution?

Comment: I wonder if you need bt_coexist. Let's check your wireless driver. Please edit your question to add the result of: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Wifi and Bluetooth signals are known to interfere each other